# Shell - use of the variable with dash

Tags: shell, init.d, opentsdb

I was reading tcollector init.sh file here: https://github.com/OpenTSDB/tcollector/blob/master/rpm/initd.sh#L25

what does the dash mean in the line 25`TCOLLECTOR=${TCOLLECTOR-/usr/local/tcollector/tcollector.py}`?

(I originally thought it just assigns the path after the dash to TCOLLECTOR; however my tests show two different results:

1. if TCOLLECTOR has already been assigned a value, it will conserve that value
2. else TCOLLECTOR will have the value "/usr/local/tcollector/tcollector.py"

I also looked at the use of "-" but it's all about STDIN and STDOUT...I didn't get a clue of how they are related to my question.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an example of *parameter expansion*; the general POSIX variety is documented [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), and you can read about the Bash incarnation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Basically, the minus sign expansion does exactly what you described: `${anyVariable-anyExpression}` expands to the value of `$anyVariable` if it is set, but if it's not set, then it expands to `anyExpression`.

The plus sign does exactly the opposite: `${anyVariable+anyExpression}` expands to `anyExpression` if `$anyVariable` has a value, and to nothing (the empty string) if it is unset.

There are several other options as well.

Comment: Thank you Mark! Since I don't have at least 15 reputations I can't vote this answer up...will do it in the future